# Tool to find columns in a database approaching limit?

Tags: mysql, profiling

Can anyone point me to a tool, script, method, query, etc. that will help me find all columns in a database that have values approaching the size limit of the column?

For example, if I happen to have a column that is a smallint(8) - the maximum value possible to store in that column is 32767.  If any of the rows in that table have a value that is say... more than 90% of that limit for that column, I would like to know.

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the size of your database, this would be a pretty resource intensive operation - one tablescan per column per table (although you may be able to get creative with that)!

Comment: Definitely resource intensive!  I would hope to run this as a monthly profiling type operation, not regularly :-)

Answer (score 0):

For integers that's easy:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.anumber > (32767 * 0.9)
```

For text you can use the length function.

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE LENGTH(a.stringfield) > 20;
```

*Note that using a function kills any chance of using an index on that field.*

Comment: Johan, while I appreciate the quick answer... I hope I made it clear in the question that I am looking for a tool or script that will automate this search for all columns in the entire database.  My goal is to not create these individual queries for every single column in the database based on the size of the column, and then run it.  That would be the benefit of having a tool or script.

Comment: Cool, but you did say: "Can anyone point me to a tool, script, method, **query**"

Comment: @Keylan You can use Information_Schema to generate queries like the one Johan showed

Comment: It's a potential SQL-injection nightmare, but you can generate the needed queries using dynamic SQL and the data in information_schema. When I have time, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Hey man, if you can find "all columns in a database that have values approaching the size limit of the column" with a single query, I'm happy to work with it! :-)  I don't think that this should require any user input - where is the possibility for SQL-injection?  I'm excited to see what you end up producing Johan!